# Помогите вырезать с текста

Tags: delphi

Доброй ночи, подскажите как вырезать из текста:

> HJ_03234 422333 100

Цифру 100, учитывая что вместо нее может быть 200 или 0. А так же два первых значения могут быть разной длинны.

Спасибо вам, в столь поздний час.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вроде как-то так:

```
const
    s : string = 'HJ_03234 422333 100';
var
    TS : TStringList;
begin
    TS := TStringList.Create;
    TS.DelimitedText := s;
```

Выйдет массив *TS.Strings*

Comment: Delimiter при этом не нужен. Пробел и так в списке разделителей.

Comment: Поправил, дабы не совершали такой ошибки=)

Comment: Незабываем FreeAndNil(TS);